# Existence of a geodesic in a complete separable metric space

Tags: analysis, reference-request, metric-spaces, geodesic, metric-geometry

If I have $X$ a complete separable metric space, $x, y \in X$ arbitrary points, how can I define a constant speed geodesic, i.e. a continuous map $g : [0,1] \rightarrow X$ such that
$$ d(g(t), g(s)) = |t-s| d(g(1), g(0)) \quad \forall t,s \in [0,1]$$
and $g(0) = x, g(1) = y$?

Comment: You will need much stronger conditions on $X$ than just complete and separable.

Comment: @NateEldredge Is compactness enough?

Comment: @user102293:  No, it's not enough.  One should at least assume path connectedness.  Even then, I'm not sure it's enough.  Consider the graph of the absolute value function, say with $-1\leq x\leq 1$ and with metric inherited from $\mathbb{R}^2$.  This is compact, complete, separable, path connected, etc, but I don't think there's a constant speed geodesic connecting points on either side of the corner point.  In fact, by using a skinner absolute value graph, it becomes obvious:  the end points are close to eachother, but there's no short geodesic between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is necessary that $X$ be a [length space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_space); this is much stronger than the topological conditions you're considering.  If $X$ is additionally locally compact, then the Hopf-Rinow theorem says that constant speed geodesics exist.  See Theorem 2.4 of [these notes](http://www.math.ethz.ch/~lang/LengthSpaces.pdf).  The local compactness assumption cannot be dropped, according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf%E2%80%93Rinow_theorem); there are infinite-dimensional counterexamples.